# finally() executed before then() completes in prepared statement execution

Tags: node.js, sql-server, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am new to node.js and I'm having an issue with connecting to an `mssql` database and preparing/executing a prepared statement.

I have the following code:

```
this.connectionPool.connect().then(pool => {
    // Create prepared statement
    stmt = new mssql.PreparedStatement(pool);

    // PREPARE
    stmt.prepare(command, err => {
        //TODO: check for errors in prepare
                
        // EXECUTE
        stmt.execute((err, result) => {
            //TODO: check for errors in execute

            // UNPREPARE
            stmt.unprepare(err => {
                //TODO: check for errors in unprepare
            });

            console.log(`Rows affected: ${stmt.rowsAffected}`);
            console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
            return result;
        });
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(`Connection pool error: ${err}`);
}).finally(() => {
    // Close connection
    console.log("Closing connection.");
    if (this.connectionPool.connected) {
        this.connectionPool.close();
    }
});
```

I'm finding that the `finally()` promise is executed at the same time as `then()`, which I wouldn't have expected. This is causing the connection to be closed before the statement can be prepared.

```
ConnectionError: connection is closed
```

How can I ensure the connection is closed only *after* the statement has been executed?

Answer (score 1):

The callbacks are executed async, so you need to add the result of the `execute` in the promise chain:

```
this.connectionPool.connect().then(pool => {
  // Create prepared statement
  stmt = new mssql.PreparedStatement(pool)

  // return a promise to add it to the promise chain
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stmt.prepare(command, err => {
      // TODO: check for errors in prepare
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      // EXECUTE
      stmt.execute((err, result) => {
        // TODO: check for errors in execute
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
          return
        }

        // UNPREPARE
        stmt.unprepare(err => {
          // TODO: check for errors in unprepare
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          }
        })

        console.log(`Rows affected: ${stmt.rowsAffected}`)
        console.log(`Result: ${result}`)
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  })
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(`Connection pool error: ${err}`)
}).finally(() => {
  // Close connection
  console.log('Closing connection.')
  if (this.connectionPool.connected) {
    this.connectionPool.close()
  }
})
```

If `stmt.prepare` support promise out of the box, you may return it without wrapping it in a `new Promise`

---

All promise version:

```
this.connectionPool.connect().then(pool => {
  // Create prepared statement
  stmt = new mssql.PreparedStatement(pool)
  return stmt.prepare(command)
    .then(() => stmt.execute())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(`Rows affected: ${stmt.rowsAffected}`)
      console.log(`Result: ${result}`)
    })
    .finally(() => stmt.unprepare())
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(`Connection pool error: ${err}`)
}).finally(() => {
  // Close connection
  console.log('Closing connection.')
  if (this.connectionPool.connected) {
    this.connectionPool.close()
  }
})
```

Comment: I believe `stmt.prepare`, `stmt.execute` and `stmt.unprepare` return a `Promise` if the callback is omitted. Would you mind showing me how that could be utilised instead of the additional `new Promise` wrapper?

Comment: I'm finding with this example that now neither the `catch()` or `finally()` methods are being executed, which means the connection is never closed.

Comment: Updated answer. If those block doesn't execute, check the last one that is executed. I think the issue could be before the call to this piece of code

Comment: In your second example I'm finding that `stmt.unprepare()` from the `finally()` method is being executed before `stmt.prepare()` and I'm getting the error `PreparedStatementError: statement is not prepared. Call prepare() first.`. This is basically the same as I was getting before where the `finally()` method was being executed first and closing the connection. Why is `finally()` not waiting until the completion of `then()`?

Comment: Could you check what is returning prepare method? I think it is not a promise for this reason it is not awaited

Comment: Yes it `prepare()` returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

The `.prepare()`, `.execute()` and `.unprepare()` methods all accept callbacks. Unless these methods are "promisified", the `this.connectionPool.connect().then().catch().finally()` chain has no means of being informed of the outcome of the prepare-execute-unprepare process.

The prepare-execute-unprepare process can be promisified as follows:

```
this.connectionPool.connect()
.then(pool => {
    let stmt = new mssql.PreparedStatement(pool);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stmt.prepare(command, err => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                stmt.execute((err, result) => {
                    if(err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        stmt.unprepare(err => {
                            if(err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                resolve(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`Prepared statement error: ${err.message}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    if (this.connectionPool.connected) {
        this.connectionPool.close();
    }
});
```

Now, the `catch()` and `finally()` blocks will be sequenced as you expect.

Comment: If `.prepare()` (and the other methods) return Promise, as you say above, then things get a whole lot simpler.